# 2 table in different database error - The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please help me with my script.

I am trying to run a script and receiving an error of:

> The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once

Here's my script.

```
MERGE [Database2].[DBO].[evt_Building Permits] AS stm 
USING (SELECT * FROM [Database1].[DBO].[PERMIT_TRACKING]) AS sd ON rtrim(ltrim(stm.BUILDING_PERMIT_NO)) = rtrim(ltrim(sd.Building_Permit_Number)) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT

WHEN Matched THEN
  UPDATE SET stm.concession = sd.prj_concession;
```

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this article about MERGE and then consider another approach. http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/ You could change this to a standard update with joins here and avoid merge entirely.

Answer (score 0):

That indicates that your source table  [Database1].[DBO].[PERMIT_TRACKING]  has  duplicate BUILDING_PERMIT_NO keys

Try to find the duplicate building permit no

```
SELECT BUILDING_PERMIT_NO,count(*) FROM [Database1].[DBO].[PERMIT_TRACKING] group by BUILDING_PERMIT_NO having  count(*) > 0
```

if you cant fix the source data make sure you have unique keys in your source query by grouping the data by BUILDING_PERMIT_NO

Comment: I run this 
SELECT  (Building_Permit_Number), count(*) FROM [ws2005PERMITS].[DBO].[PERMIT_TRACKING] group by Building_Permit_Number having  count(*) > 0

Comment: and got a result of 237/07 1
231/91 1
251/94 1
471/03 1
799/03 1
064/02 1
044/99 1
2008/0189 1
2011/0432 1 -> all are one...